# How to show that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|=\|h\|_\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(\Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $h\in L_\infty(\Omega, \mu)$. Define $T: L_p\to L_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ defined by $Tf=hf$. Note that $T$ is the bounded linear operator. Then the dual operator of $T$ is that for $f\in L_p$ and $g\in L_q$ (here $1/p+1/q=1$)
$$
(Tf, g)=\int Tf gd\mu=\int hfg d\mu=(f, hg)=(f, T^* g)
$$
Then $$T^*g=hg$$

But how to show that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|=\|h\|_\infty$?

---

Clearly, for $f\in L_p$,
$$
\|Tf\|^p=\|hf\|^p_p=\int |hf|^p d\mu\le \sup|h|^p \int |f|^Pd\mu
$$
Then
$$
\|Tf\|\le \|h\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty
$$
Thus, $\|T\|\le \|h\|_\infty$. Similarly, we can show that $\|T^*\|\le \|h\|_\infty$. But how to show that the equality can be attained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $0<\delta<\|h\|_\infty$ let $$A_\delta=\{x\in \Omega\,:\, |h(x)|\ge \|h\|_\infty -\delta\}$$ Then $\mu(A_\delta)>0.$ There exists $B_\delta\subset A_\delta,$ such that $0<\mu(B_\delta)<\infty.$ Let $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} {\overline{h(x)}\over |h(x)|}& x\in B_\delta \\ 0& x\notin B_\delta\end{cases}$$ Then $\|f\|_p=\mu(B_\delta)^{1/p}$ and $$\|Tf\|_p=\left (\int\limits_{B_\delta}|h(x)|^p\,d\mu(x)\right )^{1/p}\ge (\|h\|_\infty -\delta)\mu(B_\delta)^{1/p}$$ Therefore $$\|T\|\ge \|h\|_\infty-\delta$$ As $0<\delta<\|h\|_\infty$ is arbitrary we get $$\|T\|\ge \|h\|_\infty$$ The adjoint operator acts on $L^q$ by $T^*f=\overline{h}f,$ hence $\|T^*\|=\|h\|_\infty.$